# item pipeline not working in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written the following code and I found that item pipeline will not work if I write in the following way, the `process_item` (in item pipeline) will not be executed.

```
class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = “***”
    def __init__(self, url='http://example.com/', **kw):
        super(Spider,self).__init__(**kw)
        self.url = url 
        self.allowed_domains = [re.sub(r'^www\.', '', urlparse(url).hostname)]

    def start_requests(self):
        #return [Request(self.url, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=False)]
        return [Request(self.url, callback=self.find_all_url, dont_filter=False)]

    def find_all_url(self,response):
        log.msg('current url: '+response.url, level=log.DEBUG)
        if True:
              self.parse(response)

    def parse(self, response):
        dept = deptItem()
        dept['deptName'] = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()[0].strip()
        dept['url'] = response.url
        log.msg('find an item: '+ str(response.url) +'\n going to return item' , level = log.INFO)
        return dept
```

However, if I change the callback in start_requests from `self.find_all_url` to `self.parse` (see above the commented code), the item pipeline works, I try to find out why, but I couldn't, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that if I want to write in this way, I need to add `return` in front of `self.parse(response)` in function `find_all_url`.

But I am not very clear why this is the case, I guess the returned item should eventually return to the initial requests?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your settings?

You must define the pipelines in settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'MySpider.pipelines.SomePipeline': 300,
}
```

Basic example: https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot

Comment: why question in answer?

Comment: That does not mean that you have to answer instead.

Comment: I just want to try to help you. I think i can do-it. But if u want, you can down vote the answer an forget about-it

Comment: Oh, don't try to mislead the talk. I got your question as a reviewer. You wanted to help, that's a good thing, I really appreciate it, but you can not do what you are not permitted. Okay? @Zartch

Comment: Ok, apologize for my question in answer.